# Finding $\iint _De^{\frac{x-y}{x+y}} dy\,dx$ where $D=\{(x,y):x\geq 0,y\geq 0,1\leq x+y\leq 2\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Integrate $e^{\frac{x-y}{x+y}} dy\,dx$ over the set $D=\{(x,y):x\geq 0,y\geq 0,1\leq x+y\leq 2\}$.
I tried to do substitution $u=x-y$ and $v=x+y$ so i know that $ 1\leq v\leq 2$ but i couldn't figure how to get the boundaries for u

Comment: $u = x+y$, $v = x-y$ gives $x = (u+v)/2$, $y = (u-v)/2$. So the region on $u, v$ is given as $$ u+v \ge 0, u - v \ge 0, 1 \le v \le 2$$

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408558/321264 and the linked threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find bounds on $u$, simply convert the given inequalities in $D$: $x \geq 0$ becomes $2x \geq 0$ which can be written as $u+v = 0$, and similarly, $y \geq 0$ can be written as $v - u \geq 0$. $1 \leq x+y \leq 2$ becomes $1 \leq v \leq 2$, as you've noticed.

Do be careful; changing variables to $u$ and $v$ requires you to multiply a Jacobian factor when you integrate.

Comment: thanks for the help and somehow i got negative value after all the calculations which is weird

Comment: Actually, “weird” doesn't describe it. It simply cannot be.

Comment: yea i know ,when i calculated Jacobian $\frac{d(u,v)}{d(x,y)}=-2$

Comment: @ronkurman You're calculated the wrong Jacobian; you should use $\left\vert \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right\vert$. (Don't forget that the Jacobian here has an absolute value on it.)

Comment: @hdighfan first i forgot the abs and i can calcualte the one i wanted and then take the inverse no?

Comment: @ronkurman Indeed, you can take the inverse of what you've found. After doing this and taking absolute value, it should work.

Comment: thanks man for the help :) @hdighfan