# Where is my mistake in finding $\int_D e^\frac{x-y}{x+y}\,dx\,dy$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I'm trying to compute

$$\int_D \! \exp\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y,$$

where $D$ is the region $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $0 \leq y \leq 1-x$, a triangle in the first quadrant.

I tried to solve it using variable change, $t=x-y, s=x+y$, we can see that $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $ 0\leq s \leq 1$

as those are the exreme values for $t,s$.

The jacobian of this transform is $\frac{1}{2}$

So overall the integral i calculated is

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \! e^{t/s} \, \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}s=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \! se^{t/s} \Bigg|_{t=0}^{t=1} \, \mathrm{d}s=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \! s(e^{1/s}-1) \, \mathrm{d}s$$

I don't know how to find the antiderivative of this function, but even if i did, this integral does not converge.

Where is my mistake? because I know for a fact the correct answer is $\frac{e-1}{4}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408558/how-do-i-calculate-a-double-integral-like-iint-mathbfde-fracx-yxydx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/241883/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is the region for $t$ and $s$. Namely, we don't have $0 \leq t \leq 1$, since for example you could have $x = 0$, $y = 1$ giving $t = -1$.

The correct region is $0 \leq s \leq 1$, and $-s \leq t \leq s$.

Comment: ahhh yes ofcourse that is correct. Simple mistakes are easy to make. Thank you.

Comment: Would you please elaborate how you got $-s < t <s$?

Comment: Note that $x=\dfrac{t+s}{2}$ and $y=\dfrac{s-t}{2}$.

Comment: The answer $\frac{e-1}{4}$ seems to be incorrect. the correct answer seems to be $\frac{e-e^{-1}}{4}$