# How should I solve this integral with changing parameters?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I can't solve this. How should I proceed?

> $$\iint_De^{\large\frac{y-x}{y+x}}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$

$D$ is the triangle with these coordinates $(0,0), (0,2), (2,0)$ and I've changed the parameters this way $u=y-x$ and $v= y+x$ and the Jacobian is $-\frac{1}{2}$ but I have problem finding the range of $u$ and $v$ to calculate the integral.

Comment: Duplicate (with an enlarged domain) of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/845996 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408558

Comment: i couldn't find them at first but even after your mention i couldn't find the elaboration to draw the new region to find the new range for parameters but thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start by making a drawing of your domain. You can see that the $v$ is along the diagonal in the first quadrant, and $u$ is along the diagonal in the second quadrant. You can also see that the line between $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ is parallel to $u$, and intersects $v$ axis at $v=1$. So $v$ varies between $0$ and $1$ and $u$ varies between $-v$ and $v$.

Comment: thank you for your answer but my problem is that i can't draw my domain how should i draw u and v vectors along the y and x?

Comment: You draw a triangle $(0,0), (2,0),(0,2)$. The $x$ axis is from $(0,0)$ to $(2,0)$.  What are $u$ and $v$? You have $u=y-x$ and $v=y+x$. So if I want to draw the $u$ axis you need to go from $(0,0)$ to $u=1$ and $v=0$. The second equation means $v=0=y+x$ or $x=-y$. If you plug into $u=1=y-x=y-(-y)$ you get $y=1/2$ and then $x=-1/2$. That means that you go in the second quadrant, along the $y=-x$. Similarly, the $v$ axis means $v=1$ and $u=0$. $u=0$ means $y=x$, which is the diagonal in the first quadrant.

Comment: "So if I want to draw the u axis you need to go from (0,0) to u=1 and v=0 " why to u=1 and v=0?

Comment: If you want to draw the $x$ axis, you go from $(0,0)$ to $x=1$ and $y=0$. If you want to draw the $y$ axis, you go to $y=0$ and $x=0$.

Comment: thank you i just got the whole idea and i'm gonna choose your answer because it directly answers the parameter change that i had done in the question

Answer (score 7):

Your domain is $$D=\{(x,y):0<x<2\,,\,0<y<2\,,\,x+y<2\}$$

Using change of variables $(x,y)\to(u,v)$ with $$u=\frac{x-y}{x+y}\,,\,v=x+y$$

The region is now $$R=\{(u,v):-1<u<1\,,0<v<2\}$$

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\iint_D \exp\left({-\frac{x-y}{x+y}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y&=\frac{1}{2}\iint_R ve^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v
\\\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2v\,\mathrm{d}v\int_{-1}^1 e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}

Comment: Finally the $v$ appears, but with no explanation at all?

Comment: @NickD I have left the calculation of the jacobian to the OP.

Comment: That's fine, but you should at least mention it, if only for the sake of future readers.

Comment: It is pretty clear as it is, I think.

Comment: thank you for answering. two questions : 1- how did u end up being between -1 and 1 ?? and 2-same as @NickD how v appears at the end?

Comment: @khoshrang To see the bounds of $u$ and $v$, replace the string of inequalities in $D$ with $u$ and $v$. (So first of all, solve for $x,y$ in terms of $u,v$ ). And $v/2$ is the jacobian of course, no surprise that it appears at the end.

Comment: yeah jacobian ! i forgot about that for a minute

Comment: thank you! your new parameters are better than i had chosen in question but i'm gonna choose the other answer because it directly answers to the parameters that i had mentioned in the question

Answer (score -2):

Computer algebra gives (for the general case):

$$e \left(x^2 \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{2 x}{x+y}\right)-\frac{y^2 \text{Ei}\left(\frac{2
   y}{x+y}\right)}{e^2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} e^{1-\frac{2 x}{x+y}} (x+y)^2$$

over your specified region:

$$e-\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: yes the final answer is right due to my answer sheet but i should solve this by hand not computer any idea of how should i solve this on paper?

Comment: (-1) because this is not an answer to the question. See the other excellent responses!

Comment: @JimmySabater:  I find it absolutely astounding that the "solution" (+7 and accept) lists the trivial point of how to draw a triangle, while the full correct solution leads you to downvote.

Comment: The accepted solution takes the time to actually reply the steps to the asker. Your answer is not one bit helpful to be honest and when asker asked you a question you didnt even reply... that si the reason the accepted answer got many upvotes and the other answer too which also boh actually answer tbe qestion