# Evaluate $I=\iint_{R}(x+y)^{-3 / 2} \exp \left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right) d x d y$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Given the region $R=\{(x, y): x>0, y>0, x+y<a\}$, Evaluate $$I=\iint_{W}(x+y)^{-3 / 2} \exp \left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right) d x d y$$

I tried using change of variables.
$x+y=u$ and $y=v$
Then we have $0 \lt u \lt a$ and since $x=u-y=u-v>0$ we have $0<v<u$

The Jacobian will be $$J=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} &\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ 
 \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}& \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
1 &-1 \\ 
 0&1 
\end{vmatrix}=1$$
Thus our integral will be:
$$I=\int_{u=0}^a\int_{v=0}^{u}u^{\frac{-3}{2}} \times e\times e^{\frac{-2v}{u}}dudv$$
Is this change of variables fine?

Comment: Yes it is correct and the limits also seem correct.

Comment: One can also change variables $(x,y)\to (u,v)$ such that $u=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$ and $v=x+y$. Similar to my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3141568/321264.