# Change of Variable - Limits of Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

I find it confusing when there's a change of variable involved in a definite integral (double or triple) - in cases where the limits themselves are variable.

Here's an example to highlight my problem:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}e^{\frac{x-y}{x+y}}~dx~dy$$

The change of variable to go for is $x-y=u$ and $x+y=v$

but now, what shall be the limits of the new integral?

A friend says that the same region in the $uv$ plane would be bounded by $u=-v$,$u=v$ and $v=1$. Could someone please explain **exactly how this works**? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you sketched the region in $x, y$-coordinates, then added a pair of $u,v$-axes so you can *see* how this works?

Comment: The region in the X, Y coordinate system is the triangle bounded by $x + y = 1$ and the coordinate axes, according to me. Am I right?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845996/int-d-e-fracx-yxydxdy-where-is-my-mistake?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408558/how-do-i-calculate-a-double-integral-like-iint-mathbfde-fracx-yxydx?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the diagram for the conversion below,

$$\int_0^1dx\int_0^{1-x}e^{\frac{x-y}{x+y}}dy=\frac12\int_0^1 dv \int_{-v}^{v}e^{\frac uv}du$$
[image]

Comment: You have your $u$ and $v$ axes flipped, and the $x$ axis should be $u-v = -2y = 0 \implies u=v$, etc for the $y$ axis.

Comment: Thanks for spotting it. Corrected it