# Calculation of double integral: $\iint_D e^\frac{x-y}{x+y}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following double integral: $$I=\iint_D e^\frac{x-y}{x+y}\,dx\,dy$$ where $$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: 0\le x\le 2,\,1-x\le y\le 2-x\}$$
Let $$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
u=x+y \\ 
v=x-y
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
1\le u\le2 \\ 
-u\le v\le 4-u
\end{array}
\right.$$
After some more operations, I get: $$I=\int^1_{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1-e^{4w}}{w^3}\, dw$$ which can't be calculated with traditional methods and our teacher hasn't taught us the exponential integral. How should I proceed?

Comment: Maple outputs $$ -3/4\,{{\rm e}^{-1}}-5/4\,{{\rm e}^{3}}-4\,{{\rm e}^{-1}}{\it Ei}
 \left( 1,-4 \right) +3\,{\rm e}+4\,{{\rm e}^{-1}}{\it Ei} \left( 1,-2
 \right)
 .$$ Its numeric value is $ 4.368951404 $.

Comment: Variation on [the theme](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408558/how-do-i-calculate-a-double-integral-like-int-mathbfd-int-e-fracx-yxy?rq=1).

Comment: @user64494 I put the original integral on Wolfram Alpha and the result is exactly $4$, therefore there's something with my result. Also, I had read that post but there are no limits of $v$ that are functions of $u$, so its calculation doesn't involve the exponential function, where the problem in my question probably lies.

Comment: I can confirm @user64494 result with mathematica. The original integral evaluates to $\approx 4.36$

Comment: @Winther Then, there's some problem with Wolfram Alpha..! Still, though, is the resulting integral the right way to proceed with my solution? That's mainly the task at hand.

Comment: Also for the last integral I get: $\int_1^2\frac{u(e^{4/u}-1)}{2e}du$ after the substitution and performing the $v$-integral. Why don't you share the link where you have tried to evaluate it on  WA?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But, then I apply the $w=\frac{1}{u}$ substitution.

Comment: Then it should be $\int_{1/2}^1 \frac{e^{4w}-1}{2e w^3}dw$. You must remember to fix the integration limits.

Comment: I was wrong about Wolfram Alpha + I fixed the limits in my post.

Comment: The integral has no elementary closed form so a numerical evaluation is the way to go. Yes you can express it in terms of the so-called Exponential-integral (use integration by parts to reduce $1/w^3$ down to $1/w$ and use the [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html)), but you would anyway need numerics to evaluate the exponential-integral.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/241883/321264