# Calculate integral of function over a triangle

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $R$ be the triangle whose vertices are the points $(0,0), (0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. Calculate the following integral:
\begin{align*}
\iint_R e^{\frac{y-x}{y+x}} \,dx\,dy
\end{align*}

I think that i have to do some change of variables but i can't figure it out which one should that be. Any help?

---

### Edit

I thought about changing to variables as $u = y-x$, $v= y+x$, so the jacobian would be $-2$ and now i have to solve this other integral:

\begin{align*}
-2\iint_D e^{\frac{u}{v}} \,du\,dv
\end{align*}

Which i don't know how to solve either.

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong with the question? That's a simple exercise I have no idea how to solve so there isn't much more to say. I'd appreciate suggestions for the future.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241883/integrate-e-dfracx-yxy

Comment: Duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/331236/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2827734/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2466698/321264

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3141532/321264

Answer (score 2):

Try $u = y - x$ and $v = y+x$, since those are the terms you have. This makes the integrand easy. The Jacobian should be $\pm 2$.

Feel free to comment if this doesn't work and I'll try to give a full answer.

Comment: I tried that but still don't know how to solve the result... I'd appretiate your help :)